# нужен совет для новичка

Tags: javascript

как правильно читать learn javaScript что-бы хоть что-то запомнить от туда или посоветуйте ресурсы по изучению javaScript ))

Answer (score 1):

вот тут можно почитать, для новичка само то https://learn.javascript.ru/
Чтоб лучше что-то запомнить, нужно просто постоянно практиваться и само собой запомниться)

Comment: Также есть сайт с задачками для JS: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/
Конечно на английском языке, но это плюс, как раз английский язык подтянет

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно не являюсь сторонником платных ресурсов, но HTML Academy, несмотря на сегодняшние зверские тарифы, предлагает простой, удобный, а главное - интересный способ обучения. Мне понравилось :)